# Hiding a tab in Xamarin.Forms using Prism framework

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am working on a Xamarin Forms project that uses an MVVM pattern and Prism.

My issue is, I need to be able to hide a tab on a tab page based off of a bool. There is a bindable property in the XAML called "IsVisible", which I assumed would hide the tab from the user, but instead the tab still shows but displays a blank page when selected.

Currently my XAML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:com.XXXXXXX"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"

        BackgroundColor="White"
        x:Class="com.XXXXXXXXXX.EditChargePage"
        Title="{Binding Title}">

<local:EditChargeDetailsPage Title="Details" />
<local:EditChargeTrackingPage Title="Tracking" IsVisible="{Binding TabContext.HasTracking}" IsEnabled="{Binding TabContext.HasTracking}"/>
<local:EditChargeNotesPage Title="Notes" />


</TabbedPage>
```

Originally to solve the problem I just used "IsVisible", when that didn't work as expected I added "IsEnabled" which didn't seem to do anything.

Is there a way to hide the Tab from the UI using a boolean value in Xamarin (or Prism for Xamarin) without breaking MVVM?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [Prism Samples](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms). The `TabbedNavigation` sample demonstrates how to initialize your tabbed children with `INavigatingAware` or the `IEventAggregator`, as well as dynamically adding the tabs at run time. If you need even finer control, such as a value in a ViewModel of one of your Child Pages that determines whether some other page should be shown, then you could use this to publish an event with the `IEventAggregator` and subscribe to that event in your TabbedPage to handle adding or removing the page.

Unfortunately `IsVisible` and `IsEnabled` do not actually work within a TabbedPage the way you were hoping. So the only way you can accomplish this is to actually manipulate the Children of the TabbedPage directly pushing or popping them from the collection.

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely in the right direction. I have those samples but wasn't aware they were recently updated.

Playing around I haven't been able to both dynamically add tabs and have a tab (that isn't the first tab) display as the default tab.

Thanks again

Comment: I am trying to replicate the TabbedNavigation in my project, but when I call  NavigationService.NavigateAsync(_tabbedPagePath); I am getting the error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService.OnNavigatedTo